# How to Get .Net 5 PublishSingleFile Executable Path (temp folder)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to Get .Net 5 PublishSingleFile Executable Path (temp folder)

I tried the following codes

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

These codes in .NET Core 3.0|3.1 give the following output:

```
CurrentDirectory : C:\Users\Mahdi\source\repos\WpfAppTest\WpfAppTest\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish
AppDomain : C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\WpfAppTest\vy4mio3s.mik\
AppContext : C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\WpfAppTest\vy4mio3s.mik\
```

In .Net Core 3, **AppDomain** and **AppContext** produce exactly the output I need (**Temp\.net...**)

But the same code creates different output in **.NET 5**

```
AppDomain : C:\Users\Mahdi\source\repos\WpfAppTest\WpfAppTest\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\publish\
AppContext : C:\Users\Mahdi\source\repos\WpfAppTest\WpfAppTest\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\publish\
```

So the question is how can I find the unpacked location of the exe file in .NET 5?

Comment: .NET 5 doesn't unpack executable at the app's startup. [Single file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file) - _.NET Core host first extracts all files to a temporary directory before running the application. .NET 5.0 improves this experience by directly running the code without the need to extract the files from the app._

Comment: Thank you @aepot my mistake was to use the IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract option, so all files extracted to temp folder Now I realize that I do not need this option :)

Comment: @aepot that's not fully true. Maybe it now runs in memory or so, but is still unpacks a number of files to a temporary directory.